# Window of Console does not open second time only once

Tags: c++, mfc

So I have made my application in MFC, Visual C++ 2005 for Windows CE but I've got some weird problem.

When I press button in my Dialog Box which has to show me something in Console, I mean

```
std::cout << show_me_something;
```

It happens, I can see clearly everything I want to but when I press 'X' button to quit or in toolbar File->Close I can't open it again, it looks like Im pressing button but nothing happens.

It's like:
1. Press button to show me something
2. You see what you want
3. Close it
4. I press again same button, because I want to see it again
5. Still pressing button (nothing happens)

Here is Code of Dialog Box in which it happens:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Dialog1.h"
#include "Dialog2.h"
#include "Diaglo3.h"
#include "tScannerDlg.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <CString>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>

// Dialog2 dialog

IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(Dialog2, CDialog)

Dialog2::Dialog2(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CDialog(Dialog2::IDD, pParent)
{

}

Dialog2::~Dialog2()
{
}

void Dialog2::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    CWnd* pWnd = GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT1);
    pWnd->SetWindowText(_T("test8.csv"));
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(Dialog2, CDialog)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDOK, &Dialog2::OnBnClickedOk)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_BUTTON1, &Dialog2::OnBnClickedButton1)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_BUTTON2, &Dialog2::OnBnClickedButton2)
    ON_EN_CHANGE(IDC_EDIT1, &Dialog2::OnEnChangeEdit1)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDOK2, &Dialog2::OnBnClickedOk2)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

// Dialog2 message handlers

void Dialog2::OnBnClickedOk()
{
    //wroc
    Dialog1 *dlg = new Dialog1();

    dlg->Create(IDD_DIALOG1, NULL);
    dlg->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
    DestroyWindow();
}

void Dialog2::OnBnClickedButton1()
{  

}

void Dialog2::OnEnChangeEdit1()
{
    //nazwa pliku
}

void Dialog2::OnBnClickedButton2()
{
    //sprawdz

    CWnd* pWnd = GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT1);
    CString cstr;
    std::string s, linia;
    std::fstream fp;
    std::vector <std::string> vec;
    std::string delimiter = ";";
    std::string token;
    size_t pos = 0;
    pWnd->GetWindowTextW(cstr);

    fp.open(cstr, std::ios::in);
    if(fp.good() == true){
        printf("Cala zawartosc bazy danych:\n"             
               "----------------\n");

        while(!fp.eof()){  
            std::string linijka;
            getline(fp,linijka);
            std::cout<<linijka<<std::endl;
        }
        fp.close();
    }  

}
void Dialog2::OnBnClickedOk2()
{
    DestroyWindow();
}
```

EDIT #1:
I forgot to write it, so I do now: I think it's like I press to close this Window (std::cout) and I'm doing it but Windows CE is thinking this window is still open so that's why I can't open it again. How do you think Can I be write? And most important, how to fix this?

Comment: Please post code as text in your question instead of giving a link.

Comment: What are you pressing to close the window? Once the console window is closed, your application is gone, too. You will need to start the application again ("Run" from Visual Studio, or double-click on the EXE).

Comment: I mean if I compile my program in Windows CE, I've Dialog Box that on Button opens Another DB. In second DB I've got button that is showing me what I've got in text file. And it is showing by std::cout / printf whatever.
And when I press button it's shown, works fine. But when I close value of text file by X or File->Close it's closed but I can't open this one more time by Button in Dialog Box , but I have to Close my application and run it one more time. It's not normal.